# Bounding roots of a polynomial by coefficients

Tags: polynomials

I'm using Samuelson's [result](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-12/issue-3/Conditions-That-the-Roots-of-a-Polynomial-be-Less-Than/10.1214/aoms/1177731720.full) and a chapter from Marden's monograph "The Geometry of Polynomials". These are sophisticated results. Are these independent from the Jury-Cohn test to show that a polynomial has roots less than unity?

For expository reasons (to get a better understanding) I'd like to use the results for functions with real coefficients of second and third degree and find the restrictions on the coefficients. Is this a more difficult task than setting a polynomial $a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0 = 0$ and manipulating coefficients such that the roots $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are less than 1? Is there a result on this somewhere already? Thank you

Comment: If you are asking about bounds on the roots (which the title would seem to indicate), then Fujiwara's bound might be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Other_bounds ; however, I am not sure precisely what you are asking.

Comment: Hi András, perhaps to make it more clear, do you know of a resource to fix the roots of the polynomial to be *exactly* modulus one, and then perturbations should should which direction the inequality would move?

Answer (score 1):

For real $a,b,c$ in $ax^2+bx+c=0,$ you can get conditions on a,b,c explicitly in Mathematica using Resolve:

```
Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, 
  c + b x + a x^2 == 0 && 
   b y + 2 a x y - a y^2 == 0  , (x^2 + y^2 < 1)], Reals]
```

Here, I used the substitution $z=x+iy$ and separated real and imaginary parts.
This gives an ugly expression, but is fully automatic.

Looking at the expression, it seems very tedious to do it by hand.